# Unable to create component with outletref in Spartcus3.0.0-next.3

Tags: angular, storefront, spartacus-storefront, b2b

I am trying to create a new paragraph component after "my account" dropdown after login.
I tried to create a component after ng-reflect-position="SiteLogin" in  b2b features.

Currently using Spartcus3.0.0-next.3. Where found there is syntax change in between 2.0 to 3.0.

Steps Created are:
Created a angular component and its module was imported in app.module.ts

Imported import { OutletRefModule} from '@spartacus/storefront'; in New component module

Imported newly created component in app.component.html

Component code is

<ng-template [cxOutletRef]="SiteLogin" cxOutletPos="before" let-model>

```
  Hi This new component
```

I couldn't see newly Imported paragraph component after SiteLogin component. In Same way in 2.0 able to get the component with cxOutletRef="testComponent" but in 3.0 there is no component shown.

Am I missing any code? Can anyone please help how to get component in 3.0

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Working. There is issue in local to update of latest pre release version. Once installed with latest ng it working fine.

Comment: We're not aware of that issue, but I'm glad you've been able to get around it!

Answer (score 2):

There is no outlet available for the navigation entries inside the dropdown. The dropdown navigation itself is a cms component, and there's (currently) no more fine grained outlet for you to use.

Most customers however would control the navigations in the CMS. Perhaps that's something to consider.

Your code however should produce the template code *before* the `SiteLogin` page slot. You might face a small issue, since you seem to reference a variable `SiteLogin` rather than a string `"SiteLogin"`. You'd need to remove the surrounding brackets from the `cxOutletRef` directive:

```html
<ng-template cxOutletRef="SiteLogin" cxOutletPos="before" let-model>
  template content...
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I tried with removing brackets still not working. Tried to show before Section1
<ng-template cxOutletRef="Section1" cxOutletPos="before" let-model>
  Content
</ng-template>
Either for SiteLogin or Section1 cxOutletRef is not reflecting template 
Still not showing content. Any help on it?